# Template10 Show Busy Task Delay

Tags: c#, task, uwp, template10

I am loocking for show a Busy page meanwhile some methods are working on my Project with Template10.

Currently I have implemented:

```
await Task.Run(() => Methods());
```

I think this isn't correct because using this way some methods (with loops) are broken and the bindablebase too.

My code:

```
private static void SetBusy_NewProject(bool busy, string text = null)
{
    WindowWrapper.Current().Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
    {
        var modal = Window.Current.Content as ModalDialog;
        var view = modal.ModalContent as Busy;
        if (view == null)
            modal.ModalContent = view = new Busy();
        modal.IsModal = view.IsBusy = busy;
        view.BusyText = text;

        await Task.Run(() => Methods.Groups.Body());                
        await Task.Run(() => Methods.Groups.Steel());
        await Task.Run(() => Methods.Groups.CU());
        await Task.Run(() => Methods.Groups.FP());

        await Task.CompletedTask;
        SetBusy_NewProject(false);

    });
}
```

Can you say me the correct way to show a Busy page meanwhile some methods are working.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For use the Template10 Busy page in the Hamburger template, you only have to call the `Views.Busy.SetBusy(true, "My Loading text")` method before the Tasks and the `Views.Busy.SetBusy(false)` after the awaited Tasks. No need to copy the Busy class' code. Eg.:

```
Views.Busy.SetBusy(true, "My Loading text");

await Task.Run(() => Methods.Groups.Body());                
await Task.Run(() => Methods.Groups.Steel());
await Task.Run(() => Methods.Groups.CU());
await Task.Run(() => Methods.Groups.FP());

Views.Busy.SetBusy(false);
```